# How do I uniquely store 4 ints in one int (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit

Lets say that I have the following four ints:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
int c = 6;
int d = 7;
```

I want to store these values in one int:

```
int whole;
```

How would I do this using bitwise / shift operations? I tried:

```
int whole = a + (b << 8) + (c << 16) + (d << 24);
```

But I'm not sure if this will create unique values for whole, because I also want to retrieve the ints back from whole. So if I have, for example, whole = 5919835 I want to get the value of c back.

Comment: This cannot be unique: you cannot store 128 bits uniquely in 32 bits.

Comment: but what if integers  value can not be fit in 8 bits? you sould be able to store maximum 256

Comment: You cannot store 4 `int` in a single `int`. You can store 4 integer values in an `int` but you have to limit their range to 8 bit each.

Comment: The only way this makes sense is if you want to pack 4 bytes in a single 32-bit integer. I suspect there are a *lot* of similar questions already. There's a built-in function too, [BintConverter.ToUInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_ToUInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_). You can revers this with [BitConverter.GetBytes(UInt32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_UInt32_)

Comment: What ranges will the input integers be in?

Comment: recommendation: `byte a = 4, b = 5, c = 6, d = 7;` - now it is obvious that their range *allows* this usage, and you avoid a whole lot of risky overflow scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

You can compress `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` into a single `int` if all `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all in a range of `[0..255]` i.e. if they are in fact `byte`s:

```
 int whole = unchecked(a | (b << 8) | (c << 16) | (d << 24));
```

note `unchecked` (when `d > 127` you can have *integer overflow* since `int` is signed integer). Technically, `+` will do, but `|` (bitwise or) seems to be more readable.

Reverse:

```
a = whole & 0xFF;
b = (whole >> 8) & 0xFF;
c = (whole >> 16) & 0xFF;
d = (whole >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Bitwise operator should be `&` instead of `&&`